# OpenCv (Python) How can I detach adjacent objects

Tags: python, opencv

I want to detach adjacent two objects. I try to:

```
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_color, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,img_binary = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
img_erode = cv2.erode(img_binary, kernel, iterations = 1)
cv2.imshow('img_erode', img_erode)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

The result image:
[image]

Comment: Increase the number of iterations in the `erode` operation. Also, try other shapes for your `structuring element`.

Comment: Use watershed. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga3267243e4d3f95165d55a618c65ac6e1 and https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html and https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/11/02/watershed-opencv/